# why am I able to copy one object into other object if the class has a const variable?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

As per cppreference documentation :

> The implicitly-declared or defaulted copy constructor for class T is defined as deleted if any of the following conditions are true:
>
> - T has non-static data members that cannot be copied (have deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous copy constructors);

I am using a `const` variable inside my `Demo` class, so I am expecting that `obj1` should not copy into `obj2` because we have a `const` variable, as shown in the below example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Demo
{
public:
  const int val = 100;//nonstatic data member that cannot be copied
  Demo(){}    
};

int main()
{
    Demo obj1;
    Demo obj2(obj1);
    std::cout << "obj1.val :" << obj1.val << std::endl;
    std::cout << "obj2.val :" << obj2.val << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
obj1.val : 100
obj2.val : 100
```

Why is `obj1` copied into `obj2`? As per cppreference doc:

> "implicitly declared copy constructor deleted if you have nonstatic  data member which cannot be copied"

Comment: Why don't you think `val` can be copied?

Comment: ohh..i think we can copy but we cannot update..i understood...so could you tell me any datamember example that we cannot copy just to understand this point?

Comment: Try `std::unique_ptr<int>` or `std::mutex`.

Comment: You might want to compare your quote to what cppreference.com says about [deleted copy assignment operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Deleted_implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator) (const matters there).

Comment: Objects can be copy-constructible and/or copy-assignable (just "copyable" is a bit ambiguous). Const data members remove the copy-assignment, but not the copy constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why `obj1` copied into `obj2`? as per cppreference doc "implicitly declared copy constructor deleted

Because the implicitly declared copy ctor `Demo::Demo(const Demo&)` is **not actually deleted** in the given code as the `const` data member `val` can be copied.

---

> so could you tell me any datamember example that we cannot copy just to understand this point?

Here is a contrived example where the copy ctor `Demo::Demo(const Demo&)` is **implicitly deleted** as the const data member `val` cannot be copied.

```
class DeletedCopy
{
    public:
        DeletedCopy(const DeletedCopy&) = delete;//delete the copy ctor
        DeletedCopy() = default;
};
class Demo
{
public:
  const DeletedCopy val{};
  Demo(){}

};

int main()
{
    Demo obj1;
    Demo obj2(obj1);//this won't work now as copy ctor Demo::Demo(const Demo&) is implicitly deleted.
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Z2r99Pml5)

Answer (score 1):

**1. Your initial question:**

> Why is obj1 copied into obj2

Because having a `const` member does not mean it cannot be copied. `const` just means that once the member is initialized it cannot be modified.

**2. Your question in the comment:**

> could you tell me any datamember example that we cannot copy just to understand this point?

You'll need to add a member which is **non-copyable** in order to have the *"implicitly declared copy constructor deleted"*.
An example is [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex):

The following code produces the error message below:

```
#include <mutex>

class Demo
{
public:
    std::mutex val;
};

int main()
{
    Demo obj1;
    Demo obj2(obj1);  // <---- error below on this line
    return 0;
}
```

Error message (MSVC):

```
error C2280: 'Demo::Demo(const Demo &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

**A side note:** better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).